# [verbose]: arXiv Warning: user included plain hyperref directive

Tags: overleaf, warnings, arxiv

I uploaded my .tex, .bib, and .bbl files from overleaf on arXiv. After processing the files the log shows the following warning:

```
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'main.tex'
[verbose]: arXiv Warning: user included plain hyperref directive.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hpdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
```

The warning appears just before hpdflatex runs for the first time, so I have the impression that the actual file content is not the reason.

What does the warning mean? How do I get rid of it?

Minimal Working example that throws the warning is below. I get the warning no matter if `\usepackage{hyperref}` is activated or not.

```
\documentclass[reprint,amsmath,amssymb,aps,prapplied]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\preprint{APS/123-QED}

\title{Article Title}
\author{Author1}
\email{author@email.com}
\affiliation{University}
\date{\today}
    \begin{abstract}
        Abstract
    \end{abstract}

    \maketitle
    
    \section{Introduction}
    This is a Test. And this is a citation~\cite{boyd2008nonlinear}.

    \bibliography{main}
\end{document}
```

Comment: arXiv is injecting hyperref into all documents, So if you already have hyperref setup there might be some conflicts. It might be best to not include `hyperref` in what you upload to arXiv at all. At least that solved a similar problem the last time a user asked about this.

Comment: I tried to remove ```\usepackage{hyperref}``` but I still get the same warning.

Comment: did you try to remove the line completly? the arxiv parser perhaps  don't understand a comment sign.

Comment: Hi there, Tom from Overleaf Support here. It seems that @UlrikeFischer was right and commenting out `\usepackage{hyperref}` isn't enough, the line has to be completely removed it seems.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.

Comment: I accepted the answer given by Abraham - that should close the question I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same, removing `\usepackage{hyperref}` not commenting it out!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. This is already suggested in the comments.

Comment: This problem doesn't seem to be covered elsewhere in this forum.  Thus, it is worth keeping this answer (and question) open, as an answer in a comment in a closed question isn't likely to be found.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted the answer, so that it will be helpful for others in the future.